# uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, undefined, mootools

The following function sets the following error: "uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function javascript" worked fine before , now fails  =(  Helpme please!

```
$('longitud-grados').addEvent('change', function(event){
        var lg = $('longitud-grados').value;
        var lm = $('longitud-minutos').value;
        var ls = $('longitud-segundos').value;

        if((lg > 117) || (lg < 86)) $('longitud-grados').value = '';

        if(lg != '' && lm != '' && ls != ''){
            c = new Coordenada();
            l = c.gms2dec(lg, lm, ls, 'w');
            $('longitud').value = l.decimal;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you're using MooTools?...

Comment: What line does the error come from?

Comment: Hi! marks the error in the line: 
$ ( 'longitud-grados' ). addEvent ( 'change' ,  function ( event ){ <-- uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Looks like a more complex error. Maybe some function is not properly loaded yet. What is the error line number?

Comment: If that `$` is jQuery, there's no "addEvent" method.

Comment: And what is the `'longitud-grados'` selector?

Comment: worked well before , but updated technologies in the server and all failed.

Comment: Please indicate the **line number** and state your **framework** jQuery/Moo etc

Comment: Have you updated your jQuery version in the server?

Comment: If you do not read and respond to requests for clarification in the comments this question is unanswerable.

Comment: I'm trying to see the version of the framework , the system is programmed into joomla 2.5 and I find that this version of the framework using

Comment: The version is  v1.11.1

Comment: yes joomla using  MooTools!!

Comment: Can you post the code/link to that Class `Coordenada` I don't see any error in your MooTools code except you could spare using `$('longitud-grados')` and use `this` inside the event handler since its the same element.

Comment: lol mootools 1.11. the problem is that $('longitud-grados') does not return an element. it's probably not found so returns null, you are calling `(null).addEvent()`.

Comment: I found that the version
function(){this.MooTools={version:"1.4.5",build:"ab8ea8824dc3b24b6666867a2c4ed58ebb762cf0"}
but everything worked fine =(

Comment: [Link] http://www.cnf.gob.mx:8090/snif/portal/las-demas/areas-elegibles

This is the page with the problem! help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because $ is not defined. I had a look at your web page

```
> $('longitud-grados').
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } VM1196:732
> $('longitud-grados')
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function VM1555:2
> $
undefined
> MooTools
Object {version: "1.4.5", build: "ab8ea8824dc3b24b6666867a2c4ed58ebb762cf0", More: Object, lang: Object}
> document.id
function (D,F,E){if(D&&D.$family&&D.uniqueNumber){return D;}var l=typeOf(D);return(e[l])?e[l](D,F,E||document):null;}
```

So, for whatever reason, your $ is not defined - either do `$ = document.id;` or change your script to use `document.id('longitud-grados');`

you can also use a closure pattern around that code like

```
(function($){
    ...
    $('someid'); // will work
}(document.id));
```

keep in mind you also have `jQuery` on the page, doing `$ = document.id` may cause problems with your jQuery scripts if it's not using `.noConflict()` mode

Comment: oohhhh!!!! thank you!! DIMITAR CHRISTOFF 
The system returns to work correctly!!!! 
forgive my bad English!
thanks for your help!   ... =)